# PHP file makes webpage go blank

Tags: php, html

I'm a novice in PHP and recently changed the home page of my website from `index.html` to `index.php`. When I changed the file to PHP, it would display a white blank page. Changing the file back to HTML would restore the page back to normal.

Anybody know why the page goes blank when the extension is changed to PHP, and how I can fix it?

Comment: Showing the contents of your file would help. Also, have you installed PHP?

Comment: Did you not change the file contents in any way?

Comment: There's a thought - also, is your server configured to look for the .php extension? did you implicitly look for index.php or just index? There are countless possibilities, without code it's wild speculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some ideas:

- If there's some PHP in the file there might be errors in it, see if you can check your webserver error log
- There might be a .htaccess file that's hard coded to redirect to the html filename, see if you have a .htaccess file in that directory.
- The webserver might be configured to not read php files, see if you can check your webserver error log

Comment: There was nothing in the error log and removing the .htaccess file from the directory did nothing.

Comment: It ends up that an error in the PHP was throwing it off, but why would it show an entirely blank webpage over a small PHP error?

Comment: @PhiladelphiaRegionalWeather - unfortunately things that seem small like a missing semicolon or an unclosed bracket or brace pair (these types of errors are called 'parse errors') will cause PHP to throw a fatal error, and if you have error reporting turned down so it only shows in the logs and not on the webpage (for security - so random people can't see the errors and hack you further) then the webpage will look like a blank screen. Welcome to PHP :)  Cool language but parse errors are the worst, especially if you have people interrupting you all the time while you're coding :p